# How can I make these cards look more professionally designed?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a mental health website and there are three solutions as seen below. I am not so good at color palettes, but the colors or patterns chosen should be suitable to color blind users.

I think this looks a bit messy and unprofessional. can you suggest anything that can make it better.

Here is what the website looks like right now:
[image]

html

```css
.card1{
grid-area: card1;
background-color: #b5caaf;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='80' height='80' viewBox='0 0 80 80'%3E%3Cg fill='%239C92AC' fill-opacity='0.4'%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M41 37.59V25h-2v12.59l-8.9-8.9-1.41 1.41 8.9 8.9H25v2h12.59l-8.9 8.9 1.41 1.41 8.9-8.9V55h2V42.41l8.9 8.9 1.41-1.41-8.9-8.9H55v-2H42.41l8.9-8.9-1.41-1.41-8.9 8.9zM1 1h2v2H1V1zm0 4h2v2H1V5zm0 4h2v2H1V9zm0 4h2v2H1v-2zm0 4h2v2H1v-2zm0 4h2v2H1v-2zm0 4h2v2H1v-2zm0 4h2v2H1v-2zm0 4h2v2H1v-2zm0 4h2v2H1v-2zm0 4h2v2H1v-2zm0 4h2v2H1v-2zm0 4h2v2H1v-2zm0 4h2v2H1v-2zm0 4h2v2H1v-2zm0 4h2v2H1v-2zm0 4h2v2H1v-2zm0 4h2v2H1v-2zm0 4h2v2H1v-2zm0 4h2v2H1v-2zm4 0h2v2H5v-2zm4 0h2v2H9v-2zm4 0h2v2h-2v-2zm4 0h2v2h-2v-2zm4 0h2v2h-2v-2zm4 0h2v2h-2v-2zm4 0h2v2h-2v-2zm4 0h2v2h-2v-2zm4 0h2v2h-2v-2zm4 0h2v2h-2v-2zm4 0h2v2h-2v-2zm4 0h2v2h-2v-2zm4 0h2v2h-2v-2zm4 0h2v2h-2v-2zm4 0h2v2h-2v-2zm4 0h2v2h-2v-2zm4 0h2v2h-2v-2zm4 0h2v2h-2v-2zm4 0h2v2h-2v-2zM5 1h2v2H5V1zm4 0h2v2H9V1zm4 0h2v2h-2V1zm4 0h2v2h-2V1zm4 0h2v2h-2V1zm4 0h2v2h-2V1zm4 0h2v2h-2V1zm4 0h2v2h-2V1zm4 0h2v2h-2V1zm4 0h2v2h-2V1zm4 0h2v2h-2V1zm4 0h2v2h-2V1zm4 0h2v2h-2V1zm4 0h2v2h-2V1zm4 0h2v2h-2V1zm4 0h2v2h-2V1zm4 0h2v2h-2V1zm4 0h2v2h-2V1zm4 0h2v2h-2V1zm0 4h2v2h-2V5zm0 4h2v2h-2V9zm0 4h2v2h-2v-2zm0 4h2v2h-2v-2zm0 4h2v2h-2v-2zm0 4h2v2h-2v-2zm0 4h2v2h-2v-2zm0 4h2v2h-2v-2zm0 4h2v2h-2v-2zm0 4h2v2h-2v-2zm0 4h2v2h-2v-2zm0 4h2v2h-2v-2zm0 4h2v2h-2v-2zm0 4h2v2h-2v-2zm0 4h2v2h-2v-2zm0 4h2v2h-2v-2zm0 4h2v2h-2v-2zm0 4h2v2h-2v-2zM5 5h70v70H5V5zm2 68h66V7H7v66zM9 9h62v62H9V9zm2 60h58V11H11v58zm2-39.6V13h16.4A29.1 29.1 0 0 0 13 29.4zM15 15v6.67A31.17 31.17 0 0 1 21.67 15H15zm-2 52V50.6A29.1 29.1 0 0 0 29.4 67H13zm2-8.67V65h6.67A31.17 31.17 0 0 1 15 58.33zM67 67H50.6A29.1 29.1 0 0 0 67 50.6V67zm-8.67-2H65v-6.67A31.17 31.17 0 0 1 58.33 65zM67 13v16.4A29.1 29.1 0 0 0 50.6 13H67zm-2 8.67V15h-6.67A31.17 31.17 0 0 1 65 21.67zM39 13h2v2h-2v-2zm7.02.66l1.93.52-.51 1.93-1.94-.52.52-1.93zm6.61 2.46l1.74 1-1 1.73-1.74-1 1-1.73zm5.75 4.08l1.42 1.42-1.42 1.4-1.4-1.4 1.4-1.42zm4.5 5.43l1 1.74-1.73 1-1-1.74 1.73-1zm2.94 6.42l.52 1.93-1.93.52-.52-1.94 1.93-.51zM67 39v2h-2v-2h2zm-.66 7.02l-.52 1.93-1.93-.51.52-1.94 1.93.52zm-2.46 6.61l-1 1.74-1.73-1 1-1.74 1.73 1zm-4.08 5.75l-1.42 1.42-1.4-1.42 1.4-1.4 1.42 1.4zm-5.43 4.5l-1.74 1-1-1.73 1.74-1 1 1.73zM41 67h-2v-2h2v2zm6.95-1.18l-1.93.52-.52-1.93 1.94-.52.51 1.93zm-13.97.52l-1.93-.52.51-1.93 1.94.52-.52 1.93zm-6.61-2.46l-1.74-1 1-1.73 1.74 1-1 1.73zm-5.75-4.08l-1.42-1.42 1.42-1.4 1.4 1.4-1.4 1.42zm-4.5-5.43l-1-1.74 1.73-1 1 1.74-1.73 1zm-2.94-6.42l-.52-1.93 1.93-.52.52 1.94-1.93.51zM13 41v-2h2v2h-2zm.66-7.02l.52-1.93 1.93.51-.52 1.94-1.93-.52zm2.46-6.61l1-1.74 1.73 1-1 1.74-1.73-1zm4.08-5.75l1.42-1.42 1.4 1.42-1.4 1.4-1.42-1.4zm5.43-4.5l1.74-1 1 1.73-1.74 1-1-1.73zm6.42-2.94l1.93-.52.52 1.93-1.94.52-.51-1.93zM40 63a23 23 0 1 1 0-46 23 23 0 0 1 0 46zm0-2a21 21 0 1 0 0-42 21 21 0 0 0 0 42zm0-2a19 19 0 1 1 0-38 19 19 0 0 1 0 38zm0-2a17 17 0 1 0 0-34 17 17 0 0 0 0 34z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
border: 1px purple solid;



}


.card2{
  grid-area: card2;
background-color: #b5caaf;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 80 80' width='80' height='80'%3E%3Cpath fill='%239C92AC' fill-opacity='0.4' d='M14 16H9v-2h5V9.87a4 4 0 1 1 2 0V14h5v2h-5v15.95A10 10 0 0 0 23.66 27l-3.46-2 8.2-2.2-2.9 5a12 12 0 0 1-21 0l-2.89-5 8.2 2.2-3.47 2A10 10 0 0 0 14 31.95V16zm40 40h-5v-2h5v-4.13a4 4 0 1 1 2 0V54h5v2h-5v15.95A10 10 0 0 0 63.66 67l-3.47-2 8.2-2.2-2.88 5a12 12 0 0 1-21.02 0l-2.88-5 8.2 2.2-3.47 2A10 10 0 0 0 54 71.95V56zm-39 6a2 2 0 1 1 0-4 2 2 0 0 1 0 4zm40-40a2 2 0 1 1 0-4 2 2 0 0 1 0 4zM15 8a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4zm40 40a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
position:inherit;
}


.card3{

  grid-area: card3;
background-color: #b5caaf;
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M11 18c3.866 0 7-3.134 7-7s-3.134-7-7-7-7 3.134-7 7 3.134 7 7 7zm48 25c3.866 0 7-3.134 7-7s-3.134-7-7-7-7 3.134-7 7 3.134 7 7 7zm-43-7c1.657 0 3-1.343 3-3s-1.343-3-3-3-3 1.343-3 3 1.343 3 3 3zm63 31c1.657 0 3-1.343 3-3s-1.343-3-3-3-3 1.343-3 3 1.343 3 3 3zM34 90c1.657 0 3-1.343 3-3s-1.343-3-3-3-3 1.343-3 3 1.343 3 3 3zm56-76c1.657 0 3-1.343 3-3s-1.343-3-3-3-3 1.343-3 3 1.343 3 3 3zM12 86c2.21 0 4-1.79 4-4s-1.79-4-4-4-4 1.79-4 4 1.79 4 4 4zm28-65c2.21 0 4-1.79 4-4s-1.79-4-4-4-4 1.79-4 4 1.79 4 4 4zm23-11c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5s-2.24-5-5-5-5 2.24-5 5 2.24 5 5 5zm-6 60c2.21 0 4-1.79 4-4s-1.79-4-4-4-4 1.79-4 4 1.79 4 4 4zm29 22c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5s-2.24-5-5-5-5 2.24-5 5 2.24 5 5 5zM32 63c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5s-2.24-5-5-5-5 2.24-5 5 2.24 5 5 5zm57-13c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5s-2.24-5-5-5-5 2.24-5 5 2.24 5 5 5zm-9-21c1.105 0 2-.895 2-2s-.895-2-2-2-2 .895-2 2 .895 2 2 2zM60 91c1.105 0 2-.895 2-2s-.895-2-2-2-2 .895-2 2 .895 2 2 2zM35 41c1.105 0 2-.895 2-2s-.895-2-2-2-2 .895-2 2 .895 2 2 2zM12 60c1.105 0 2-.895 2-2s-.895-2-2-2-2 .895-2 2 .895 2 2 2z' fill='%239C92AC' fill-opacity='0.4' fill-rule='evenodd'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
 <div class="card card1">
<br>

    <a href="breathing-tool.html">Rhythmic Breathing Guide</a>
<br>
<br>
    <p> Proper breathing helps to reduce anxiety by increasing the flow of oxygen throughout the body. 
      <br> <br>
      This excercise is designed to deliver the best timing of deep breathing suggested by health specialists.
      <br> <br>
      Practice this for 5 to 10 minutes daily. 
    </p>
    </div> 


<div class="card card2">
     
<br>
      
  <a href="pink-meditation.html">Pink Meditation</a>
<br>
<br>
  <p> This is a medititation space to help calm and reduce anxiety.</p>

 <br>
   <p> This design was inspired by the psychological calming effects of the colour pink which has been used in famous arts.  </p>
<br>
   <p> Please use this for no more than 20 to 30  minutes a day, as long periods of exposure to pink can have adverse effects. </p>
    </div> 

       
      

      <div class="card card3">
   <br>
 <a href="quote-generator.html"> Quote Dispenser</a>
       <br>
       <br>
       <p> This is a collection of quotes that you can read when you need to be inspired or calmed down. </p>
<br>
       <p> A motivational quote has the power to affect your mood leading to possitive changes to the way you act and react. </p>
<br>
      <p> Reading a few of these possitive quotes at the beggining of the day can make a possitive impact on your mindset. </p>
        </div> 


          
</div> <!--this is the closing tag of "column"-->
```

Comment: This is rather opinion-based, so it will probably be closed, but I'd recommend considering adding more padding for the text, maybe a whiter background behind the text...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about aesthetics, not programming.

Comment: I find my inspirations at https://dribbble.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If design is not easy for you, start by looking what's already available on the net to find what you like. This might help you find your way.

### Find some good images

For free images, use [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/s/photos/soul) with keywords like *nature*, *meditation*, *zen*, *soul*, *mind*, *health*, *yoga*, *peaceful*, *freedom*, etc.

You can then create a palette of colors from an image with [color.adobe.com](https://color.adobe.com/fr/create/image) or [coolors.co](https://coolors.co/).

### Look at existing templates

Have a look at existing web templates such as [Wix](https://fr.wix.com/website/templates), [Themeforest.net](https://themeforest.net/search/nature).

### Find other design ideas

Use other designer web sites like [creativemarket.com](https://creativemarket.com/templates), [freepik.com](https://www.freepik.com/), [Behance.net](https://www.behance.net/) or [dribbble.com](https://dribbble.com/) (proposed by Karma Blackshaw).

### Good references

Also have a look at good references like [Smashing magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/guides/), [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/) or [A list apart](https://alistapart.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Try creating better font(you can center it, use other font types and colors, make better text padding)

The navbar should be styled better(mabye try to make the options take 100% of the width and you can use the`sticky` property so the navbar follows you when you scroll down the site)

You have much unused space between the cards(you can turn navbar to sidenavbar and use the formal navbarspace for the logo for example)

try to make the links bigger(and change the color etc. since they seem to be titles too)

you can use other colors for background. Heres a color palette generator:

https://coolors.co/

Comment: its only for helping out since this question will be closed in no time